# Регистрация и авторизация с помощью cookie

Tags: веб-программирование, php, cookie, регистрация, авторизация

Начал освежать знания по php. Просматривая видеуроки на http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLYZm5HGThGRBZ3ym2Ek0h4jQvYAxuPLBe я узнал, что используя сессии для регистрации и авторизации пользователей, при закрытии браузера и открытии его снова теряется факт входа в аккаунт пользователя, поэтому в этих видеоуроках было сказано, что необходимо использовать cookies (т. к. они сохраняются на жестком диске пользователя). Просмотрев видеоуроки на http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qFxUApU6104&list=PLYZm5HGThGRBZ3ym2Ek0h4jQvYAxuPLBe , http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ASdD2gasVsA&list=PLYZm5HGThGRBZ3ym2Ek0h4jQvYAxuPLBe , http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nyk60llAcMc&list=PLYZm5HGThGRBZ3ym2Ek0h4jQvYAxuPLBe , http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ysmj-iQGkII&list=PLYZm5HGThGRBZ3ym2Ek0h4jQvYAxuPLBe я попытался написать регистрацию и авторизацию с использованием cookies, код которых приводится ниже. Я думал, но не удалось достичь фиксации входа в аккаунт при закрытии и открытии браузера. Помогите написать, используя сookies, с учетом, что их может существовать несколько для одного пользователя в случае, если человек по каким-то причинам решил создать несколько аккаунтов для одного сайта, регистрацию и авторизацию c сохранением входа на сайт. Привожу код

```
<?php

    $connect = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('tutorials');

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $login = $_POST['login'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $r_password = $_POST['r_password'];

        if ($password == $r_password){
            $password = md5($password);
            $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('', '$username', '$login', '$password')");
            //setcookie($login, $password, time() + 3600*24*7, "/");

        }
        else
        {
            die('Passwords not match');
        }
    }

    if (isset($_POST['enter'])){
        //echo "OK";
        $e_login = $_POST['e_login'];
        $e_password = md5($_POST['e_password']);

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='$e_login'");
        $user_data = mysql_fetch_array($query);

        if ($user_data['password'] == $e_password) {
            setcookie($e_login, $e_password, time() + 3600*24*7, "/");
            echo '<form method="post" action="register.php">
                    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="| Username" required /><br>
                    <input type="text" name="login" placeholder="| Login" required /><br>
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="| Password" required /><br>
                    <input type="password" name="r_password" placeholder="| Repeat password" required /><br>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" /><br>
                    </form>';
            echo 'You have already logged in<br>
                 <form method="post" action="register.php">
                 <input type="submit" name="logout" value="Logout" />
                </form>';           
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Wrong password or login";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        setcookie($e_login, $e_password, time() - 3600*24*7, "/");
        echo '<form method="post" action="register.php">
                <input type="text" name="username"  placeholder="| Username" required /><br>
                <input type="text" name="login" placeholder="| Login" required /><br>
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="| Password" required /><br>
                <input type="password" name="r_password" placeholder="| Repeat password" required /><br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" /><br>
                </form>';

        echo '<form method="post" action="register.php">
              <input type="text" name="e_login" placeholder="| Entered login" required /><br>
              <input type="password" name="e_password" placeholder="| Entered password" required /><br>
              <input type="submit" name="enter" value="Enter" /><br>
              </form>';
    }

?>
```

Comment: несколько аккаунтов для одного сайта - вполне возможно, только запоминание будет в одном варианте - под каким аккаунтом последним входили, тот и запомнится...

Answer (score 2):

Как-то непонятно у вас все получается. Ведь вы будете сохранять куке для того, чтобы человек мог выйти из браузера, зайти - и он уже залогинен. Но вы хотите, чтобы можно было сохранять несколько куков. Не знаю, почему у вас родилось это желание, но объясните мне - каким образом сайт поймет, какой из этих куков выбрать для проверки авторизации человека? Вы не можете присвоить на одно название куки несколько разных вариантов - можете только перезаписать. Но вы можете создать несколько разных куков - но как вы будете проверять их, я не пойму. 
Скажите вашим пользователям, которые хотят создать несколько аккаунтов, и находиться на всех них в браузере сразу залогиненым - что это невозможно.

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте, думаю вопрос решится:

1. [Безопасный метод авторизации на PHP](http://habrahabr.ru/post/13726/)
2. [Авторизация на сайтах на PHP. Про cookie простым языком.](http://www.niceseo.ru/avtorizatsiya-na-saytah-na-php-pro-cookie-prostyim-yazyikom.html)

Answer (score 0):

Можно сохранить несколько кук, но каждая из них будет отвечать за свой домен или, если чуть усложнить код создания куки, то каждая кука будет отвечать за свою страничку.